# parenting with Automatic weights but the mesh moves really weird

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

Im following this tutorial and i susessfully parented the armature to the mesh but the mesh moves really weird, is this an issue?[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]